# Changing Panel Width & Color

Tags: 11.04, panel

After increasing the width of my Panel, I got something like

[image]

How can I fix this color issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a theme bug. The panel is using an image background that doesn't fit  the width you're trying to use.

You will have either to change the background image at: `/usr/share/themes/<Your_Theme's_Name>/gtk-2.0/panel.png`

Or edit gnome-panel.rc file (`gksu gedit /usr/share/themes/<Your_Theme's_Name>/gtk-2.0/apps/gnome-panel.rc`
) and put `#` before the line with 
`bg_pixmap[NORMAL] = "img/panel.png"`